# Java KeyBindings not reacting on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, jcomponent

I have previously used Java's KeyListener, but as my programs are demanding more I have gotten the recommendation to switch over to KeyBinds.

First of all I have tried to add keybindings to JFrame which didn't work ( I don't understand what JComponent I need to use. ). Therefore I tried moving the program over to a JPanel and then adding it to a JFrame, however the Key bind do not react when the desired button is pressed (in this case it's the "1" button);

In the method call I have set the action to be Print "Hi". Here is the code:

```
public class Panel extends javax.swing.JPanel {
JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
/**
 * Creates new form Panel
 */
public Panel() {
      addKeyBinding(Panel, KeyEvent.VK_1, "1Button", (evt)->{
          System.out.println("Hi");
    });
    initComponents();
}
```

.....
And here is the method
.....

```
public static void addKeyBinding(JComponent comp, int keyCode, String id, ActionListener actionListener){

    InputMap im = comp.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    ActionMap ap = comp.getActionMap();

    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, 0, false),
        id);

        ap.put(id, new AbstractAction(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    actionListener.actionPerformed(e);
                }

    });

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: can post your complete code in comment. Pastebin?

Comment: *I have tried to add keybindings to JFrame which didn't work* - for global level bindings you add the key bindings to the root pane of the frame. Use the `getRootPane()` method of the JFrame.

Comment: Then I do `[Frame Name].getRootPane()` ? Because this did not work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key bindings are for your form panel, right? I think you're misunderstanding a few concepts about classes and objects. Also it's hard to help without seeing the full code. But your error is very likely caused by this line:

```
addKeyBinding(Panel, KeyEvent.VK_1, "1Button", ...
```

which should be:

```
addKeyBinding(this, KeyEvent.VK_1, "1Button", ...
```

The variable `Panel` should be replaced with the keyword `this` thus referencing the actual form panel.

It also should be created wherever you're creating your window so this line can also be removed:

```
JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
```

There are many things wrong with your code. I can't imagine the code in the first  snippet even compiles. You are trying to name a variable the same as your classname.

Your class has no reason to extend JPanel since it isn't a new type of JPanel. Simply remove your extends. Then change the first line to:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
```

Then pass lower-case panel to the `addKeyBinding` method.

If for some strange reason you want to keep your class extending JPanel then pass `this` as the first parameter to `addKeyBinding` as /u/tiiv said and remove the `JPanel Panel = new JPanel` line since that isn't needed (as you have it written now your class *is* the JPanel).

As far as which component to use `JFrame` is a top-level container so that is usually your main application window. And then you put JPanel and other components in the JFrame. There are actually 4 top-level containers in swing (JFrame, JWindow, JDialog, and JApplet) but JFrame is generally the one you will use as your main app window.

I hope that helps.

Comment: This helped a lot! Thank you. The code did in fact still compile :). Anyhow, Why would it be bad to keep the class extending JPanel? Also, we can't use keybindings on JFrame, and other top level containers?